# Load 64-bits Dll on Python2.2(32-bits)

Tags: python, dll, 32bit-64bit, printers, python-2.2

I am using **Python 2.2**, a **32-bit process**, but I need to load a **64bit dll** from a printer. It might seem strange, but is this possible?

Comment: Why are you using Python 2.2? That is 2001 software! Pythn 2.7 will be Python-level compatible with all features existing in 2.2.

Comment: A work order, the system is done in python 2.2, can not be used other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to load a 64-bit dll into a 32-bit process?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8787556/222914)

Comment: I've never seen that *any* DLL can be loaded with Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word, no.

`ctypes` using `LoadLibrary` is used to connect to an external DLL, but if you are a 32-bit process then you will be using 32-bit addresses, so a 64-bit binary could not be mapped against your address space.